# OpenCV canny; output image is pure gray

Tags: c, opencv

I am learning opencv and reading a book and following examples. The book introduced the canny filter. However there is some problem with my output. As an input image I have given a 512x512 gray scale image but the filter output is pure gray image. Here is the image:

This is the input image.

[image: This is the input image.]

And this is the output image.

[image]

And here is the snippets:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include "Resources.h"

IplImage* doCanny(
    IplImage* in,
    double lowThresh,
    double highThresh,
    double aperture
) {
    if (in->nChannels !=  1)
    {
         return 0; // Canny only handle gray scale images.
    }

    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(
        CvSize(cvGetSize(in)),
        IPL_DEPTH_8U,
        1
    );

    cvCanny(in, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* image = cvLoadImage(IMAGE_FRUIT);

    IplImage* output = doCanny(image, 200, 201, 1);

    cvNamedWindow("Canny", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvShowImage("Canny", output);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseImage(&output);
    cvDestroyWindow("Canny");

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2015, OpenCV version 2.4.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you step through your code, you will realize the cvCanny function never gets triggered, the returned output from doCanny is a null pointer.

OpenCV's Canny edge detection algorithm only accepts gray scale image, which is why the original code has the "if (in->nChannels !=  1)" check, so you need to convert your input image into a grayscale image first.

```
// Convert to grayscale first
IplImage* gray_image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Perform Canny
IplImage* output = doCanny(gray_image, 200, 201, 3);
```

Additional, I think your "aperture" parameter for cvCanny is also invalid, try to use the default value 3 (or 5, 7), and you should be able to see the result.

I would also recommend using the C++ interface instead of the deprecated C interface.

Comment: Yeah. I have debugged the code and indeed the image is not gray scale, value of `in->nChannels` is 3, so it is not get called.